# Write.table and txt file exporting in R

Tags: r, export

When I used `write.table` function to export a big object ( 136,419 observations and 922 variables) as a txt file, the exported file lost all variable names and had an extra first column which is c(1:136,419).

How can I avoid this issue?

Comment: Please provide some sample code in order to reproduce your problem.

Comment: If my answer works - could you please approve it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Set the `write.table()` function's settings to `row.names = FALSE` to eliminate the extra first column, and `col.names = TRUE` to keep all variable names.